Forest Plot in HR
I want to create a forest Plot of hazard ratios and 95% CI in R.

# Load the necessary packages
library(forestplot)
library(metafor)

# Define the studies and their corresponding HR, CI, and p-values
study_names <- c("Lange et al. (2023)", "Backhaus et al. (2022b)", "Podlesnikar et al. (2020)", "Kanaji et al. (2019)", "Reindl et al. (2019)", "Eitel et al. (2018)")
HR <- c(0.94, 0.94, 0.922, 0.98, 0.95, 0.94)
lower_CI <- c(0.91, 0.92, 0.882, 0.95, 0.92, 0.92)
upper_CI <- c(0.96, 0.96, 0.965, 1.01, 0.97, 0.96)
p_values <- c(0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.14, 0.0001, 0.0001)  # Replace with your actual p-values

# Create a dataframe
df <- data.frame(study_names, HR, lower_CI, upper_CI, p_values)

# Calculate the standard errors from the p-values
df$SE <- sqrt(df$p_values)

# Calculate the weights
df$weights <- 1 / (df$SE^2)

# Create the forest plot
forestplot(labeltext = df$study_names,
           mean = df$HR,
           lower = df$lower_CI,
           upper = df$upper_CI,
           weights = df$weights,
           xlab = "Hazard Ratios",
           col=fpColors(box="darkblue",line="darkblue", summary="darkred"))

# Add a vertical line at the overall mean HR
abline(v = mean(df$HR), col = "red", lwd = 2, lty = 2)

How to adjust so that I can include a vertical line and weight?
I don't know how to add the vertical line, and percentage, and the value of HR beside of forest plot like this.


Here is a solution
library(dplyr)
library(forestplot)

# Calculate the weights
df$weights <- round(1 / (df$SE^2),2)

# Forest plot
df %>% forestplot(labeltext = c(study_names, weights),
       mean = HR,
       lower = lower_CI,
       upper = upper_CI,
       zero = mean(HR),
       weights = weights,
       xlab = "Hazard Ratios",
       col=fpColors(box="darkblue",line="darkblue", summary="darkred"),
       grid = 0.9453333, # mean of df$HR
       shapes_gp = fpShapesGp(grid = list(gpar(lty = 2, col = "red"))))%>%
       fp_add_header(
       study_names = c("Study"),
       weights = c("Weigth"))


